# How to find location (e.g. character number) of substring within string (MS Excel)

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet full of cells containing >13,000 different strings of genetic code (each about 100-300 characters in length, composed entirely of A's, G's, C's and T's). Each cell looks roughly like this

ACGC**CCTTT**GCGATATTTTAATGGCCGCGAAAATATGCGGGATGCAAGCGCCGTT

I have determined that about 75% of all the strings contain a 5-character-long sequence of interest: "CCTTT". Within the ~10,000 strings containing at least one instance of the CCTTT substring, I want to know the location where the CCTTT substring begins/ends. Is there a formula that will return the length of any string prior to the beginning of the CCTTT substring? So that applying that formula to the example cell given above would return a value of 4 (there are four characters before the beginning of the CCTT substring).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula to count the length prior to "CCTTT" : =FIND("CCTTT",A1,1)-1.
Use this formula for a count of where it ends : =(FIND("CCTTT",A1,1)-1)+5 , which simply adds the the length of the snippet of searched for code. Should that length vary later ( the snippet ), you can change the "+5" to "+len(Snippet)".

If there is more than one occurrence of the substring "CCTTT" within the string, this formula counts characters prior to the second one : =FIND("CCTTT",$A1,FIND("CCTTT",$A1,1)+5)-1. The "end point" of the second one : =(FIND("CCTTT",$A1,FIND("CCTTT",$A1,1)+5)-1)+5.

Comment: @AKGreene : I would suggest wrapping an IFERROR function around the formulas to avoid errors messages if the sub-strings are not found : 
=IFERROR(FIND("CCTTT",A1,1)-1,"").